# mysql join statement

Tags: mysql

I have a category page in which i am displaying all images coming under a particular category...I also have a dropdown using which i can sort the images based on number of stories written for that image...
To accomplish this i am using JOIN statement coz media and story are two different tables...

```
media table has mediaid,catid,userid,link
```

and

```
story table has storyid,mediaid,storyheading,storycontent
```

i am using JOIN statement in this way...

```
SELECT count(story.id) as cnt,story.mediaid as id,media.cat_id,media.link,media.userid 
FROM story RIGHT JOIN 
media ON story.mediaid=media.mediaid where cat_id='25' group by story.mediaid order by cnt desc limit 0,8
```

but i get only the images that has stories...i wanted all the result such that even if there is no story for a particular image we can show 0 stories...can we do that by not changing the table structure and just changing the sql statement??
Please help...*-*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to flip your SQL and use LEFT JOIN instead:

```
SELECT count(story.id) as cnt, media.mediaid, media.catid, media.userid, media.link
  FROM media LEFT OUTER JOIN story ON media.mediaid = story.mediaid
 WHERE media.catid = '25'
 GROUP BY media.mediaid, media.catid, media.userid, media.link
 ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

the `right join` is ok, the `group by story` is the problem: you want to group by images, don't you?

try `group by media.mediaid`  instead!